# Convert keras model from pb file to tflite file

Tags: android, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert a trained Keras model from `.pb` file to `.tflite` file:

```
tflite_model = tf.contrib.lite.toco_convert(frozen_graph_def, input_tensors, output_tensors)
```

However, when I run this code, there is an error that says:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.lite' has no attribute
>   'toco_convert'

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows it won't work since toco library does not support windows. So it's better to switch over Linux and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the last version of tensorflow? this can also be solved when installing tf-nightly. Or compiling tensorflow from the source with bazel.
You can also use instead: `tf.contrib.lite.TocoConverter.from_frozen_graph(final_model_path, input_arrays, output_arrays)`

Answer (score -1):

Please provide the tensorflow graph you are trying to convert to reproduce the exact error. It would help to also file an issue on GitHub https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues